# How can i resolve 301 redirection Issue on my website?

Tags: redirect, headers

When I scan my website on (https://www.woorank.com/en/www/fusionfirst.com)

[image]

I already use canonical tag on my header section.

Please check and help me :)

Comment: What is the content of .htaccess file?

Comment: At first glance it looks like you're using client side redirects to switch from HTTP WWW to HTTPS. I guess woorank might not be picking that up, but it does look like that redirect target is OK in the report. Is that what you're trying to solve? What's generating that client-side redirect? Can you switch that to a 301 instead?

Comment: But it might also just be showing you the wrong error: if you can solve its UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_CERTIFICATE error then this might go away too.